# How should I go about coding an IME for Windows? (7 and below)

Tags: windows, ime

I would like to program an IME for Windows for East Asian languages which are not well-supported natively yet.  This would require candidate lists.

For now, I would like to try programming a basic model which remaps keyboard characters to output phonetic characters.

Not too sure where to start though, haven't managed to find many resources on coding your own IME.